# Overload parameter does not work (maybe because of framework)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

So i copied a sample of a website. Its about deserializing YAML into a object graph. I pasted the code into my projekt and most of it works. All the usings are the same. There is only one problem.

`var deserializer = new Deserializer(namingConvention: new CamelCaseNamingConvention());`

Here a new deserializer instance is created. but my vs underlines namingconvention red. The only difference of my project and the sample, is that my project uses .net core framework and the sample uses .net as a framework. I have honestly no actual clue what the difference between .net and .net core is apart from the fact that .net core is mostly used for server applications, and .net is used for normal applications. (I think lol)

Here is the sample I copied: **https://dotnetfiddle.net/HD2JXM**

Here is the error message: [image: errore message]

Comment: Which NuGet package is `Deserializer` in (presumably YamlDotNet, but it's worth saying that in the question), and which version of it are you using? I don't see how this is related to ASP.NET Core though. I think it's *much* more likely to be about the version of YamlDotNet that you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see it's preferable to use `DeserializerBuilder` in latest versions of the library so the code becomes

```
var builder = new DeserializerBuilder();
var deserializer = builder
    .WithNamingConvention(CamelCaseNamingConvention.Instance)
    .Build();
```

According to [release notes v4.0.0](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/releases/tag/v4.0.0)

> The constructors of `Serializer` and `Deserializer` are now obsolete
> Except for the parameterless versions. The `SerializerBuilder` and `DeserializerBuilder`
> classes should now be used to configure and create instances of the (de)serializer.